# Why is QtGui.QApplication working but marked as undefined in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyside

In my Python 2.7.3 application, using PySide 1.1.2 and Qt 4.8.4, I do the following:

```
from PySide import QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

The code is working fine, with some more commands afterwards the Qt window is correctly created. However, in Eclipse/PyDev `QApplication` is underlined red and the mouse over popup says

```
Undefined variable from import: QApplication
```

Is there any way to fix this in Eclipse/PyDev?

Comment: Try going to window>preferences>interpreter - python>forced Builtins(tab)> click the new button on that tab and add PySide

Comment: I have to ask. Did you try to restart Eclipse/PyDev? When I was using it for Java I had to do that every now and then when it refused to update the error marker(s).

Comment: Great, thank you very much. After adding `PySide` to the forced builtins and restarting Eclipse the problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to window>preferences>interpreter - python>forced Builtins(tab)> click the new button on that tab and add PySide

Comment: Didn't work for me. LiClipse still shows the "Undefined variable from import for QApplication and QWidgets.